# How to pass/set UserPrincipalName attribute in AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-membership

How to set `UserPrincipalName` attribute
when default provider is `AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.

Following is the list of `CreateUser` methods of `System.Web.Security.Membership`

```
public static MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password);
public static MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email);
public static MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
public static MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) MSDN documentation, the `UserName`property are mapped to the `userPrincipalName` attribute.